# Extract sub-string between multiple certain words using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, error-handling, regex-group

## Regex sub-string

I want to extract **Phone, Fax, Mobile** I get from string if not It can return null string. I want 3 list of Phone, Fax, Mobile from any given text string string example are given below.

```
ex1 = "miramar road margie shoop san diego ca 12793 manager  phone 6035550160 fax 6035550161 mobile 6035550178  marsgies travel  wwwmarpiestravelcom"
ex2 = "david packard electrical engineering  350 serra mall room 170 phone 650 7259327  stanford university fax 650 723 1882 stanford california 943059505 ulateecestanfordedu"
ex3 = "stanford  electrical  engineering  vijay chandrasekhar  electrical engineering 17 comstock circle apt 101  stanford ca 94305  phone 9162210411"
```

It is possible with regex like this:

```
phone_regex  = re.match(".*phone(.*)fax(.*)mobile(.*)",ex1)
phone = [re.sub("[^0-9]","",x) for x in phone_regex.groups()][0]
mobile = [re.sub("[^0-9]","",x) for x in phone_regex.groups()][2]
fax = [re.sub("[^0-9]","",x) for x in phone_regex.groups()][1]
```

> **Result from `ex1`**:
> phone = 6035550160
> fax = 6035550161
> mobile = 6035550178

`ex2` does not have a **mobile** entry, so I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> phone = [re.sub("[^0-9]", "", x) for x in phone_regex.groups()][0]
> **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'**

**Question**
I need, either a better regex solution, as I am new to regex,
or, a solution, to catch **AttributeError** and assign `null string`.

Comment: Could you, please, format properly? And add what you have tried, what doesn't work, what is the expected result and what you get?

Comment: Hi, please elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve, what your issue is and what you've already tried to solve the issue. Cheers :)

Comment: I edited the question. Help would be appreciated @Toto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.search`

**Demo:**

```
import re

ex1 = "miramar road margie shoop san diego ca 12793 manager  phone 6035550160 fax 6035550161 mobile 6035550178  marsgies travel  wwwmarpiestravelcom"
ex2 = "david packard electrical engineering  350 serra mall room 170 phone 650 7259327  stanford university fax 650 723 1882 stanford california 943059505 ulateecestanfordedu"
ex3 = "stanford  electrical  engineering  vijay chandrasekhar  electrical engineering 17 comstock circle apt 101  stanford ca 94305  phone 9162210411"

for i in [ex1, ex2, ex3]:
    phone = re.search(r"(?P<phone>(?<=\phone\b).*?(?=([a-z]|$)))", i)
    if phone:
        print "Phone: ", phone.group("phone")

    fax = re.search(r"(?P<fax>(?<=\bfax\b).*?(?=([a-z]|$)))", i)
    if fax:
        print "Fax: ", fax.group("fax")

    mob = re.search(r"(?P<mob>(?<=\bmobile\b).*?(?=([a-z]|$)))", i)
    if mob:
        print "mob: ", mob.group("mob")
    print("-----")
```

**Output:**

```
Phone:   6035550160 
Fax:   6035550161 
mob:   6035550178  
-----
Phone:   650 7259327  
Fax:   650 723 1882 
-----
Phone:   9162210411
-----
```

Comment: as I am using python 3.6 It is showing me "error: bad escape \p" error

Answer (score 3):

You may use a simple `re.findall` like this:

```
dict(re.findall(r'\b({})\s*(\d+)'.format("|".join(keys)), ex))
```

The regex will look like

```
\b(phone|fax|mobile)\s*(\d+)
```

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/Q76jXg/1).

**Pattern details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(phone|fax|mobile)` - Group 1: one of the words listed
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/t0SFdJ):

```
import re
exs = ["miramar road margie shoop san diego ca 12793 manager  phone 6035550160 fax 6035550161 mobile 6035550178  marsgies travel  wwwmarpiestravelcom",
   "david packard electrical engineering  350 serra mall room 170 phone 650 7259327  stanford university fax 650 723 1882 stanford california 943059505 ulateecestanfordedu", 
   "stanford  electrical  engineering  vijay chandrasekhar  electrical engineering 17 comstock circle apt 101  stanford ca 94305  phone 9162210411"]
keys = ['phone', 'fax', 'mobile']
for ex in exs:
    res = dict(re.findall(r'\b({})\s*(\d+)'.format("|".join(keys)), ex))
    print(res)
```

Output:

```
{'fax': '6035550161', 'phone': '6035550160', 'mobile': '6035550178'}
{'fax': '650', 'phone': '650'}
{'phone': '9162210411'}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand what you want.. and it has to do with getting exactly the first match after a keyword. What you need in such a case is the question mark ?:

" '?' is also a quantifier. Is short for {0,1}. It means "Match zero or one of the group preceding this question mark." It can also be interpreted as the part preceding the question mark is optional"

And here is some code that should work, in case the definition wasnt enough

```
import re
res_dict = {}
list_keywords = ['phone', 'cell', 'fax']
for i_key in list_keywords:
    temp_res = re.findall(i_key + '(.*?) [a-zA-Z]', ex1)
    res_dict[i_key] = temp_res
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response Its not exactly what I needed

Answer (score 2):

I think the following regexes should work fine:

```
mobile = re.findall('mobile([0-9]*)', ex1.replace(" ",""))[0]
fax = re.findall('fax([0-9]*)', ex1.replace(" ",""))[0]
phone = re.findall('phone([0-9]*)', ex1.replace(" ",""))[0]
```

Comment: I appreciate your help